# TypeError: xhrReq.abort is not a function

Tags: xmlhttprequest, typeerror, abort

```
var xhrReq;
function tpvAjaxPost(json) {
  if(xhrReq !== undefined) {
      xhrReq.abort();
      xhrReq = undefined;
  }
  xhrReq = $.post("inc/ajax/tpv.php", json, function (data) {
      if(typeof (data['message']) !== 'undefined') {
          tpvHandleErrors(data['message']);
      } else {
          tpvHandleResults(json['action'], data);
      }
  }, "json").always(function() { xhrReq = undefined; });
}
```

Why am i getting : TypeError: xhrReq.abort is not a function ????

Comment: Did you log or alert the value of `xhrReq` or `typeof xhrReq` before attempting to call `abort`?

Comment: Yes, xhrReq is undefined if request has completed (good) and object if pending request (also good).

Comment: It´s like xhrReq no longer contains the XMLHTTPRequest object returned by $.post alltrough it is an object but abort method is not there?

Comment: Damn this is frustrating..

Comment: So it is an object but what _kind_ of object?  What do you see when you expand the object in your developer tools in your browser?